# Enabling VT-x on Intel Core i5 3450 with MSI B75A-G41 mainboard

Tags: bios, virtualization, vt-x

I'm willing to enable the VT-X virtualization technology on my Intel Core i5 3450 CPU, however in the BIOS menu (I've the latest version: 17.8) of my MSI B75A-G41 mainboard, this option is greyed out even though it should be supported by my CPU.

[image: Image of the BIOS Menu] "Bios menu with the VT-D option greyed out"

CPU-Z Report stating that my CPU does support VT-X:
[image: i.stack.imgur.com/vq19h.png]

Does someone know why the option is greyed out even if the "Intel Virtualization Tech" option is enabled and works fine?

Maybe do I need to install some Intel software that will activate the option on my CPU? Here are the different available utilities for my mainboard: http://www.msi.com/product/mb/B75A-G41.html#/?div=Driver
I could install all of them but I don't want to because it would slow down my computer for nothing.

Comment: Sorry about images not being embedded, and links without the http prefix: this is a restriction of superuser because I'm a new member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proccessor does not support virtualization technology VT-D ([source](http://ark.intel.com/products/65511/)), CPU-Z is correct, your CPU does have VT-x and is enabled by default as MSI utility states (`Intel Virtualization Tech - [Enabled]`)

VT-d is Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O, and MSI utility is correct once again `Intel VT-D - [Disabled]`), because it is not supported.

You cannot enable something that is not supported.